# Draw a shape over a view

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an activity with several ListViews in it. I need a rectangle with transparent background that overlaps some of the ListViews and I got lost a little.

I have some drawing coordinates that are known after all views are loaded and I want to put the graphics above the views programmatically.

Should I create a separate view that overlaps the activity window and draw on it or use the existing views? How do I start?

Comment: A simple FrameLayout should be able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this in your layout xml:

```
<View android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

if you want views to overlaps another views use relative layout and build it correctly.

Comment: Thanks and how can I do it programatically? Currently I have a linear layout. Can I draw on it after it's been inflated?

Comment: i think you cant do this. you can just create a view, set his attributes like you want programatically and than add the view in his new place but not on other views.